# Deploying C# WinForm applications works on most machines, but not all

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment

I have made a winform application for my company to use, as we are using it to replace some functionality of other internal applications, and I am to make sure the application works on all machines (mostly bare-bones machines with just .NET 4+).

The application will not load at all on one user's machine, and I have added logging functionality, but it does not help in this case, as this user cannot load the application.

I have made sure of the following sanity-checks:

1. The proper .NET configuration is installed on the user's machine
2. Made sure all of the DLLs that the program uses are referencing the DLLs in the location of the application
3. The application works for all other machines tested including...

   1. Another dev machine
   2. My dev machine
   3. Multiple barebones non-development machines

I have all of the DLLs required for the application to work, and nothing needs to be installed in the GAC.

Is there something else that I might be missing?

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: "The application will not load at all on one user's machine". Did you check the windows EventViewer? you might see an error description there

Comment: For a Net application to run you either have to have the exact same version of Net on the build and the deploy PC; or publish application and install using setup.exe like any commercial purchased software.

Comment: A Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable? A fancy Antivirus?

Comment: @Stefan

There is no error at all.

The user goes to run the application, and nothing happens. It works on other machines tested, and it is supposed to make a WinForm and a systray icon.

Comment: @Jimi

I thought there might be a fancy antivirus on his machine, but am not quite sure. I will check for that, as our company is only supposed to use one single antivirus program.

Comment: @jdweng

If I am going to have to publish the application, I will need to be able to make sure that we have network locations for the DLLs that need to be installed into the GAC in order to run.

Comment: The dlls are automatically stored in the correct locations and you probably will need admin privileges.  The dll are store just like updates to dlls that are done when you update windows.

Comment: I second @ZoharPeled and his hint at the windows event viewer. It shows the error if a .NET application can't start.

Answer (score 0):

This could be permission issues, Anti-Virus preventing the application from running or a virus itself ending the life-cycle of the application (OnStart of the event).

Try to deploy on a VM again or another machine if it works, do a reset of the machine in question.